# How to get the value from drop down selection using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, select, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to develop a custom drop down component using list elements in react. Found the, following work around very promising, but I am bit confused how to change the default value when an item is selected from the drop down. For example: initially "Select movie" is selected and when I select an item like: "The prestige" it should appear in the field.

Can be check the demo here in the following link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-williams-8je1y?file=/src/Dropdown.jsx

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted - _not_ just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestions,I have tried to update my questions...

Comment: Okay, so what part of _“Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, in text form & properly formatted”_ did you not understand then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the following, you have to use the `title` prop as a default value of a new state:

```
  const [dropdownTitle, setDropdownTitle] = useState(title)
```

then use the `dropdownTitle` as the display value for the dropdown:

```
  <p className="dd-header__title--bold">{dropdownTitle}</p>
```

Lastly set the `dropdownTitle` whenever you select or click an item:

```
  function handleOnClick(item) {
    setDropdownTitle(item.value)
    // rest of the code
```

I modified your sandbox, check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-fog-98wce?file=/src/Dropdown.jsx

Comment: hey, thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for, just one more thing if it is possible also, when in the drop downs we have two items like: {items.value} and { items.size}, would it be possible to to do like this: setDropdownTitle ( items.value, items,size). something like this?to display both item name in the field,I have edited my sandbox based on yours...

Comment: were you able to get the fix?